# Modifying some java applet code

Tags: java, graphics

I have the following applet code below and I would like to modify it so that the first and last dot in each row is colored red. I'm really having trouble getting started with this.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChineseCheckerboardApplet extends Applet {
    public void init() {
        add(new ChineseCheckerboard(this));
    }
}

class ChineseCheckerboard extends Canvas {
    public ChineseCheckerboard(Applet parentApplet) {
        setSize(400, 400);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < holesInRow.length; i++)
            drawRow(g, i);
    }


    void drawRow(Graphics g, int row) {
    int centerX = getWidth() / 2;           // figure out center of display
    int startY = 0;
    int numHoles = holesInRow[row];
    int rowWidth = numHoles * holeDiam + (numHoles-1) * holeGap;    //row width is        number of holes + appropriate number of spacings
    int startX = centerX - rowWidth / 2;            // Starting horizontal position is centerX less half the row width
    int y = startY + row * (holeDiam + holeGap);    // Vertically position based upon which row you're displaying
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < numHoles; i++) {            // Draw each hole
        g.fillOval(startX + i * (holeDiam + holeGap), y, holeDiam, holeDiam);
        g.drawOval(startX + i * (holeDiam + holeGap), y, holeDiam, holeDiam);
    }
}

final int holeDiam = 15;
final int holeGap = (int)(holeDiam * 0.25);

// Here's the array containing the number of holes per row

int [] holesInRow = {1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

}

Comment: Don't call `setSize` on applets, the size of the applet is defined by the html code that loads it, not the applet code.  Besides, the applet is using a layout manager, so it won't have any effect on the `ChineseCheckerboard`.  Any reason why you're using AWT libraries?

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like...

[image: Star]

A simple `if` statement to change the condition of the dot on each iteration of the dots over the rows is all that is needed...

```
for (int i = 0; i < numHoles; i++) {            // Draw each hole
    if (i == 0 || i == numHoles - 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    g.fillOval(startX + i * (holeDiam + holeGap), y, holeDiam, holeDiam);
    g.drawOval(startX + i * (holeDiam + holeGap), y, holeDiam, holeDiam);
}
```

Comment: Great answer to a terrible question.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Oh, come on.  It's not that bad a question.  Despite the close reason, the OP clearly expressed what she needed, and demonstrated what she _had_ been able to achieve.  But yes, this is indeed a good answer.  Also, the graphic is good, especially as it serves to illustrate that the end result was not quite the same as "make all the boundary dots red" (which would have been a more interesting question).

Comment: Good point... It wasn't expressed very well though.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think the core problem revolves around the fact that it reads a little like "I found this code and want to modify it" rather than I "wrote this and now want to modify it" - but that's just me...

Comment: What difference does it make who the author of the original code was?  Remember that we're trying to build up a database of questions and answers here.  Unless there are copyright issues, I can't see what difference it makes who actually wrote the code.  This is not a bad question - I've certainly seen far worse.  This did not deserve to be closed, and it certainly does not deserve the current tally of downvotes.  (And yes, the "reopen" vote is mine)

Comment: @DavidWallace Didn't downvote, don't vote for closure ;), but I think people are tired of a lack of effort on the part of posters, I'm just saying, not arguing ;)

Comment: I know.  Unfortunately, the people who did downvote or closevote this are unlikely to return to it and see my comments.